# downgrading QT-5.7 to QT-5.4 in Yocto( morty 2.2) for nitrogen6sx

Tags: qt5, yocto, build-system

I am compiling yocto source for `nitrogen6sx` and try to downgrade the
QT version from `QT-5.7 to Qt-5.4`and I am getting below error
click on link for full error [qt_base eroor](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3rnrpm2mo1vzu6/log.do_compile.txt?dl=0)

steps to down grade:
vi `qt5-git.inc`    change the version name

```
    make[4]: *** [.obj/qkmsintegration.o] Error 1
| make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/siva/yocto/imx6s_morty/morty/boundary-eval-image/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-mx6qdl-fslc-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.4.2+gitAUTOINC+2cb17c1fb9-r0/build/src/plugins/platforms/kms'
| make[3]: *** [sub-kms-make_first] Error 2
| make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| compiling .moc/moc_qlinuxfbscreen.cpp
| rm -f libqlinuxfb.so
| linking ../../../../plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so
| mv -f libqlinuxfb.so ../../../../plugins/platforms/
| make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/siva/yocto/imx6s_morty/morty/boundary-eval-image/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-mx6qdl-fslc-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.4.2+gitAUTOINC+2cb17c1fb9-r0/build/src/plugins/platforms/linuxfb'
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/siva/yocto/imx6s_morty/morty/boundary-eval-image/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-mx6qdl-fslc-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.4.2+gitAUTOINC+2cb17c1fb9-r0/build/src/plugins/platforms'
| make[2]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/siva/yocto/imx6s_morty/morty/boundary-eval-image/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-mx6qdl-fslc-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.4.2+gitAUTOINC+2cb17c1fb9-r0/build/src/plugins'
| make[1]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/siva/yocto/imx6s_morty/morty/boundary-eval-image/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-mx6qdl-fslc-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.4.2+gitAUTOINC+2cb17c1fb9-r0/build/src'
| make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at
```

Comment: I also got same error could anyone got solution?? please

Comment: Could you show steps that you have done for downgrading?